# How to connect Flink and Elasticsearch in Pyflink?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

I aim to create a project related to **Kafka > Flink > ElasticSearch > Kibana** with real time processing.

I can consume messages from Kafka in Flink but can not to connect Flink and ElasticSearch. How can I send kafka messages Flink consumed to  ElasticSearch?

My python 3.8 environment includes: apache-flink=1.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Table API` to create an `Elasticsearch Sink` table:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/python/table/python_table_api_connectors/#how-to-use-connectors

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/elasticsearch/#how-to-create-an-elasticsearch-table

If you need to convert your DataStream to the Table API you can find some help in here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/

Comment: This might be helpful as well (connector for Elasticsearch in PyFlink): https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/api/python//_modules/pyflink/datastream/connectors/elasticsearch.html